# What is the max number of "concurrent" requests supported by PHP Guzzle?

Tags: php, concurrency, guzzle

PHP Guzzle allows you to make concurrent requests, but you have to specify the "concurrency" number as a parameter.

For example:

```
$client = new Client();
$pool = new Pool($client, $generator($url, $data), [
  'concurrency' => 5,//this lets you set how many concurrent requests can be made
  'fulfilled' => function($response, $id) {
```

What is the maximum number of concurrent requests supported?

Answer (score 3):

There are no limitations to this value. By default, it would be [25](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Pool.php#L44).